# Set Listview Column Element visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So my issue is. I have a listview with various rows. in one row i have a Button to do a certain procedure on the data in that row. 
the thing is this Button should not be visible depending on data in the same row. 
ie. the row data might be something like:

Name , Age, Address, ID Number, HasApplied ,(Button)

in this instance the button should not appear if the bool value has applied is true. 
i have tried using boolean to visibility converters but i can't seem to get it to work.

any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option is to use a ViewModel and do the conversion in a property like IsApplyEnabled. When it's false hide the button. Or you can bind the button to a RelayCommand with a CanExecute override. This would automatically disable the button. You can also override the template to have the Button hide itself when it's disabled. Many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: yeah. i am just working on the UI at the moment. as soon as i put viewmodels in i think this is the route i will take. cheers

Answer (score 1):

The BooleanToVisibilityConverter converts true to visible, you want one that does the opposite:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class BoolToOppositeVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var boolValue = value as bool?;

        return boolValue.HasValue && boolValue.Value
            ? Visibility.Collapsed
            : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: although for this instnce i am going to use mvvm properties. i have used the converter in another implementation. cheers